# Execute form with onClick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, onclick

I have a link

`<a href="/post/$postid" class="link">Update</a>`

When I click on it it goes to a unique page defined by a variable `$postid`.

However, I want to add an onclick event which will update the database too.

I have read on here that AJAX is the best way to do this, but I'm struggling on how to write it.
From reading various questions I have come up with this:

```
<script>
$(".link").click(function() {
  // sql request
  UPDATE comments SET status='updated' WHERE user_id='$myid' AND id='$postid';
});
</script>
```

Obviously this syntax is wrong. Could somebody point me in the right direction of the type of syntax I can use to update my MySQL database with?

UPDATED WITH ATTEMPT:

Here is one attempt I have tried...

```
<form>
<a href="/post/$postid" class="link">Update</a>
</form>

<script>
$(".link").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"/application/views/notification_action.php",
        data: "myid=$user_id&postid=$postid"
        }).done(function( data ) {
            doAsYouPlease();
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

**notification_action.php**

```
<?php

$myid = $_POST['user_id'];
$postid = $_POST['pin_id'];

$query("UPDATE comments SET status='updated' WHERE user_id='$myid' AND id='$postid'");

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

However nothing works. The link just surfs to the post page like normal. nothing gets updated.

Comment: database can be accessed only in server side. Try googling for PHP and MYSQL tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file(or files) that handle(s) ajax requests (**ajax.php** in this example).

```
<script>
$(".link").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data: "ajax=1"
        }).done(function( data ) {
            doAsYouPlease();
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, so would this redirect to ajax.php or would it execute ajax.php before redirecting the the `a href` link?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
<input type="submit">
```

then change your form action to a page that submits the query, then use the

```
header("location: $postid");
```

on the same page that does the query, and it will redirect you